# Notation of keeping 1 digit without rounding and ignoring decimals?

Tags: notation

I have a data set and I want to represent in a formula that I have to keep the first digits before proceed, ignoring decimals and zeros. (no rounding)

i.e.

$2.55555 => 2$

$999999 => 9$

$0.00001 => 1$

Comment: It should be possible to extract this number directly out of the data, without computing any logarithms. To this end we would have to know the format in which the data are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\lfloor x/10^{\lfloor log_{10}(x)\rfloor} \rfloor
$$

Comment: $\left\lfloor 10^{\{ log_{10}(x)\}} \right\rfloor$, where $\{y\}$ is the fractional part of $y$, is more transparent in my opinion. It's really the same thing, though.

Comment: clever... how you get the fractional part in c++?. I guess in the same way than floor, with a function?

Comment: Yeah, $\{y\}$ is the same as $y-\lfloor y\rfloor$ (which explains the translation between our versions). I think `y%1` might actually work in c++, I know it does in some languages.